# a:hover:before - can't seem to understand what it does?

Tags: css

So I actually ran into some code which uses this selector and I can't really seem to get it.

I've also tried to search on Google but I didn't get a clear answer.

My question is:

Is this selector selecting (sorry for the weird way to say it) a pseudo-element (before) before the a:hover or is it used this way to select the hover state of a:before?

Thanks.

Comment: It adds a pesudo-element before a hovered-on `a` tag.

Comment: I've made this before the question was closed, Have a look and next time, do some search
https://jsfiddle.net/hnp6bvq5/1/

Comment: Thanks to you both. I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `a:hover::before` essentially does, is when you hover on the `<a>` tag, the following styles are applied to a psuedo element before the `<a>` tag.

The psuedo-selector `::after` does the same, but it puts the content after the tag by default, rather than before.

Consider the following snippets:

```css
a:hover { background: red; color: white; }
```

```html
<a>hello</a>
```

```css
a::before { content: 'boo'; background: red; color: white; }
```

```html
<a>hello</a>
```

```css
a:hover::before { content: 'boo'; background: red; color: white; }
```

```html
<a>hello</a>
```

Further reading on MDN: [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)